# "Done" Button Does Not Work To Dismiss a XIB Screen in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uibutton

When updated to Xcode 9, weird glitch showed up where the "done" button or "close" button does not properly work to dismiss a screen (xib).

Here's my code in .m file: 
[image: .m code]

Here's the code in .h file: 
[image: .h code]

Here's the xib file:

[image]

The "done" button is not an image. It's text.

Here's how the xib looks on a device: 
[image]

I cannot close / dismiss this screen and get back to the app.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you set any AutoLayout constraints on this view? Otherwise, iOS is probably rendering it at the default size set in Interface Builder, and it's overflowing the bounds of the screen because it doesn't know it shouldn't

Comment: seems like a layout problem. the button is there, but just out of screen.

Comment: if you are presenting that XIB file then you have to dismiss that XIB using self.dismissviewController, if you pushing your viewcontroller then you can use popviewcontroller